How to set a global hotkey without pyautogui getting in the way
So essentially I have a global hotkey registered in my Python program using the 'keyboard' library. It listens for the key event 'ctrl+shift+x' to restart the application. I have one script within my program that uses openCV for object detection in a game and during one of the interactions, it has to hold down the shift key using pyautogui to perform the action. During that, if I try to press my global hotkey, it won't register unless I spam it. It's most likely because of pyautogui holding down shift. I've tried different key combinations too that don't utilize shift, but no progress there.
So I have this code in my primary interface:
class PrimaryInterface(QMainWindow):
    requestRestart = Signal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("-----")
        self.resize(450, 300)
        self.networkManager = QNetworkAccessManager(self)
        self.setupUI()
        self.checkVersionUpdate()

        self.listener_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.registerGlobalHotkey())
        self.listener_process.start()
        self.requestRestart.connect(self.restartApplication)

        def registerGlobalHotkey(self):
        keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+shift+x', self.requestRestart.emit)

    def restartApplication(self):
        # Ensures all operations are stopped before restart
        self.cleanupBeforeExit()
        QApplication.quit()
        QProcess.startDetached(sys.executable, sys.argv)

    def cleanupBeforeExit(self):
        # Cleanup code
        keyboard.unhook_all_hotkeys()

        self.networkManager.clearAccessCache() 

and this is part of my script that performs the automation with pyautogui:
   def dropItems(self, gameplay_screen, last_slot_image):
        if last_slot_image is None:
            print("No last slot image provided.")
            return
        
        # Define the entire inventory area
        inventory_x, inventory_y = 545, 203  # Top-left corner of the inventory
        inventory_width, inventory_height = 197, 264   # Size of the inventory area

        inventory_img = gameplay_screen[inventory_y:inventory_y+inventory_height, inventory_x:inventory_x+inventory_width]

        if last_slot_image.ndim == 3:
            last_slot_image = cv2.cvtColor(last_slot_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        if inventory_img.ndim == 3:
            inventory_img = cv2.cvtColor(inventory_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # Perform template matching over the entire inventory area
        res = cv2.matchTemplate(inventory_img, last_slot_image, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
        threshold = 0.7 
        loc = np.where(res >= threshold)

        pyautogui.keyDown('shift')
        first_slot_processed = False

        try:
            for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):  # Switch x and y positions
                game_location = (pt[0] + inventory_x + last_slot_image.shape[1]//2, pt[1] + inventory_y + last_slot_image.shape[0]//2)
                if not first_slot_processed:
                    self.gwm.smooth_move_and_random_click(game_location, radius=8, smooth_time_min=0.9, smooth_time_max=1.8)
                    first_slot_processed = True
                else:
                    self.gwm.smooth_move_and_random_click(game_location, radius=8, smooth_time_min=0.1, smooth_time_max=0.3)
                time.sleep(random.uniform(.02, .05))
        finally:
            pyautogui.keyUp('shift')

this function is part of my primary while loop in the same script. While it's performing that function, I can't smoothly press my global hotkey to exit out and restart my application.

maybe you should use other programs for global hotkeys instead of python - like AutoHotKey on Windows or AutoKey on Linux

@furas I need to package my python code into a single executable using pyarmor/pyinstaller, so I don't think using autohotkey with that is feasible since it's a whole separate program essentially. I'm surprised Python doesnt have something more robust like autohotkey.

if you want to pack in .exe then it changes problem :) BTW: autokey on Linux is created in Python :). But as I know PyQt`` may have function to assign global hotkeys- but it still would need to code to pressshitf. Maybe you could use keyboardto pressshiftand maybe it would work. BTW: probablykeyboardalready usesthreadingto run code - so maybe it doesn't needmultiprocessing. If you would reduce code then we could test it - but I uses Linuxso it may work in different way (ie. on Linuxkeyboard` needs admin privileges)

@furas Thank you for the suggestions! I actually just tried to switch libraries and pynput ended up working for me surprisingly. I ran my script again and was able to press my hotkeys while pyautogui was holding shift :) So pynput is definitely the way to go for global hotkeys

I switched over to using pynput for a global hotkey listener and it worked perfectly. For some reason the keyboard library was not doing it for me whenever my pyautogui is interacting with the keyboard as well, but pynput was able to perform what I needed with the hotkey combination.


I need to package my python code into a single executable using pyarmor/pyinstaller, so I don't think using autohotkey with that is feasible since it's a whole separate program essentially.

It is probably irrelevant to you now since you achieved your goal, but for the future you should know that AutoHotkey has a functionality that allows you to compile a script written in AHK language into an executable.
All you have to do is right click the script when in your file explorer and select Compile Script (GUI)... to open a window that allows you to select various options regarding the executable you are about to create, as shown in the picture I attached: AutoHotkey Compile Script GUI
